# Android - WebViewClient loads pages extremely slowly

Tags: android, browser, native, webviewclient

As a developer, I have had pretty bad experiences when it comes to building apps (with web pages) that run on the Android webviewclient on 3G connection. A few of my users are saying that some pages take up to 10 minutes to load. (I don't know if they have exaggerated because they are frustrated.) Personally, I use HTC Desire running Android 2.2 and have tested my apps with my own phone. Indeed, even for apps that use locally stored web pages to make AJAX requests, it is extremely slow on 3G. Most of the time, it will just timeout and show up a blank page. When it's on WIFI, it works fine and is real fast.

I have heard many say that the native browser on Android 2.2 is extremely fast. For me, I must however say that the native browser app is also very slow on 3G. Sometimes, the Google mobile home page does not even finish loading. I'm in Singapore and so 3G coverage should be fine in most places.

Is it the device hardware that is causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of device specific performance issues specifically related to WebView load times. However, you may want to add both a request timeout and a network connectivity change listener. For additional information you can time requests and report back device and connectivity information on slow requests.

```
handler = new Handler();
WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    final long WEBVIEW_REQUEST_TIMEOUT = ...;
    final long WEBVIEW_SLOW_REQUEST_THRESHOLD = ...;
    Runnable onRequestTimeout = null;
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, final String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon); // current impl is no op but be fwd compatible
        saveRequestStartTime();
        onRequestTimeout = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handleRequestComplete(url, WebViewClient.ERROR_TIMEOUT);
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(onRequestTimeout, WEBVIEW_REQUEST_TIMEOUT);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url); // current impl is no op but be fwd compatible
        handleRequestComplete(url, 0);   // Return 0 onSuccess. All WebViewClient defined errors < 0. 
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl); // current impl is no op but be fwd compatible
        handleRequestComplete(failingUrl, errorCode);
    }

    private void handleRequestComplete(String url, int errorCode) {
        if (onRequestTimeout != null) {
            handler.removeCallbacks(onRequestTimeout);
        }
        onRequestTimeout = null;
        final long elapsedTime = getRequestElapsedTime();
        if (elapsedTime > WEBVIEW_SLOW_REQUEST_THRESHOLD) {
            reportSlowRequest(elapsedTime, url, errorCode);
        }
        clearRequestTime();
    }

    private void saveRequestStartTime() {...}
    private long getRequestElapsedTime() {...}
    private void clearRequestTime() {...}
    private void reportSlowRequest(long elapsedTime, String url, int errorCode) {...}
});
```